# Why does Visual Studio generate warning CS620 when passing KeyValuePair enumeration to FormUrlEncodedContent constructor?

Tags: c#, syntax, compiler-warnings, .net-5

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace dla.test2{
    internal class Test{
        public static void Main(){
            var map=new Dictionary<string,string>(){
                ["hello"]="world"
            };
            using var foo=new FormUrlEncodedContent(map);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the constructor of `FormUrlEncodedContent` yields the following compiler warning at build-time:

> Warning
> **CS8620** Argument of type 'Dictionary<string, string>' cannot be used
> for parameter 'nameValueCollection' of type
> 'IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string?, string?>>' in
> 'FormUrlEncodedContent.FormUrlEncodedContent(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string?,
> string?>> nameValueCollection)' due to differences in the nullability
> of reference types.

The [documentation for FormUrlEncodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent.-ctor?view=net-5.0) indicates the constructor should accept an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>?`. My `map` variable, being a `Dictionary<string,string>`, would presumably implement the interface `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` so I'd expect there to be no problem here. **So why the warning?**

I'm using Visual Studio 16.8.0 targeting NETCore5.

Comment: Because `string` != `string?` (eg "due to differences in the nullability of reference types").

Comment: But couldn't a non-null string, like I have here, *always* be submitted as an argument when a nullable string (string?) is expected? I understood "string?" to mean the string could be either null or non-null, but perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: _"couldn't a non-null string...always be submitted as an argument when a nullable string (string?) is expected?"_ -- not as a type parameter, no. It also wouldn't be allowed (without a warning) as a by-reference parameter, for that matter. You need to keep in mind that these positions for types involve both input and output; it's not sufficient to guarantee that you won't pass a null value...you also need to guarantee that you can _accept_ a null value, should the called method wind up providing one. See my explanation below.

Comment: Note that generic type variance respects the nullability rules correctly. I.e. `IEnumerable<string?>` parameter can accept `IEnumerable<string>`, since the covariant type parameter promises that the provided values are only output, not input, and likewise `IEnumerable<string>` parameter _won't_ accept `IEnumerable<string?>`, because a null value might be returned by the latter, and the former is expecting only non-null values. This works for contravariant type parameters as well (i.e. `...<in T>` for an interface declaration), but of course goes the other direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like there are actually a couple of questions here:

1. Why is the documentation wrong? And,
2. Why is the warning emitted.

The latter is easier to answer. The former, not so much (you'd have to ask Microsoft).

I don't have .NET 5 installed yet. But I can reproduce the exact same warning in .NET Core 3.1 with this code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var map = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        ["hello"] = "world"
    };

    M1(map);
}

static void M1(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string?, string?>>? nameValueCollection) { }
```

It's possible to infer from the warning you copy/pasted into your question what the *actual* declaration of the .NET 5 version of the `FormUrlEncodedContent` class constructor must be, so I just wrote an example that doesn't require .NET 5 to be installed.

And indeed, if we look at [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ddd1fc4af25b64b867452da43ab7dd95f0b6eccc/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/FormUrlEncodedContent.cs), we can see the actual declaration of that constructor:

```cs
public FormUrlEncodedContent(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string?, string?>> nameValueCollection)
```

This tells me that the documentation is inaccurate, if not outright incorrect. I haven't been following the changes to the framework for supporting nullable reference types, so I'm not sure if the documentation is expected to show nullable type parameters for this sort of situation. Seems to me it *should*, but clearly it's not. At the very least, it's surprising to me that the documentation shows the `nameValueCollection` parameter itself as nullable (which in fact it's not), never mind that it shows the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` type parameters as non-nullable, when in fact they are nullable.

But regardless, by understanding what the *actual* method signature is in .NET 5, we can then say that the warning is there simply because indeed, your call involves passing a type that is inconsistent with the nullability of the type parameters.

Why should this generate a warning? Well…while we know in this case no code will be writing to the nullable values in the values of the enumerable, there's no compile-time *guarantee* of this. Since your object is returning objects where the values are non-nullable references, and you pass this to a method that is declared as accepting values which are nullable, that means that in theory, that method could *modify* those nullable values by setting them to `null`, violating your own code's assumption that the values are non-nullable.

Comment: I see what you're saying but wouldn't the KeyValuePair<string?, string?> bit imply that one could submit something with a null key? Isn't that impossible in a map? A null value I could understand, but a null key?

Comment: The prohibition on null keys comes from the dictionary object itself; it's not inherent in `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. And that prohibition is not mirrored by the `FormUrlEncodedContent` object; i.e. it doesn't mind if you pass in a null key for a key/value pair. So there's no reason to specify a non-nullable string for the key type parameter in `KeyValuePair<...>`. Because you're using a dictionary to initialize the collection, you can't provide a null, but there are other ways to provide `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.